# Keeping MasterTableView row selected in SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

In my SplitViewController, based on an action in the DetailViewController, I update the MasterViewController row using NSNotificationCenter essentially like this:

[Keeping MasterViewController and DetailViewController in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316595/keeping-masterviewcontroller-and-detailviewcontroller-in-sync/10527023#10527023)

The problem is, once an update to the row of the MasterViewController is done, the row is no longer selected.  When I look at Apple's iPad apps using splitViews, like the Note application, a row is always selected.  I want to do the same thing so everything stays in sync between my two tables.  I can manually just `setSelected:YES animated:NO` on the row since I have the indexPath of the tableView, but I still do see the blue highlight of the selected row flicker off before getting set on again.  I don't want that.

MasterViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        Scene *object = [[[DataManager sharedInstance] sceneArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of the delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I updated the method.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key - set this property on the UITableViewController:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
```